# Wicket static resources are sometimes empty

Tags: wicket

It sometimes happens that static wicket resources are empty files (tested in IE7, IE11 and firefox), therefore users cannot use modal windows, etc. Clearing the browser cache often solves this temporarily, but it keeps happening more often. 
We haven’t found a way to reproduce this situation.
We have Wicket 1.5.10 running on OC4J 10.1.3.5.0 (we depend on Java 1.5) and use the default resource caching strategy.
Even on our development environment, most basic infra (no reverse proxies, etc.) , this issue (rarely) occurs.

Files we found, that sometimes become empty:

```
http://<server>/<application>/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.modal.ModalWindow/res/modal-ver-2A907789599C2AFBF81240C47EB2655E.js
http://<server>/<application>/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.WicketAjaxReference/wicket-ajax-ver-EE9CA4F0AAB28E94F63408F7494C6EEC.js
http://<server>/<application>/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WicketEventReference/wicket-event-ver-DF3B8CC0510EDA687422979E5B93FDE7.js
http://<server>/<application>/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.modal.ModalWindow/res/modal-ver-2123B7EF99557C05DF0F17782FF111B8.css
```

Static resources of our own, do not have this problem!

I haven’t found any documentation on how these files are generated, could there be a timeout?
Could we test this directly on the application server?

Any pointers to resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The files are not generated. They are plain static files located in the classpath. Wicket "generates" only their names - it inserts the hash sum of the file in the file name. This way if you upgrade Wicket and it has newer version of such resource you will get the new version, instead of the cached by the browser old version.

The problem could be both in Wicket itself and in the web server...